# Implied exception class difference between version of ruby

Tags: ruby

Sorry for the strange title, I'm not really sure how to classify this issue. I'm in the process of updating some ruby code to 1.9.3, and am seeing some strange behavior. Distilling the issue, I get:

```
def convert(exception)
  raise exception.message
end

begin
  convert(StandardError.new(StandardError))
rescue => e
  puts e.class
end
```

In 1.9.2, the output is

```
StandardError
```

and in 1.9.3, te output is

```
RuntimeError
```

Looking though the ruby docs and release notes hasn't really given me any clues as to what could be going on here, and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that prior to 1.9.3, [`Exception#message`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html#method-i-message) returned an object of class `Class`, *not* `String`, which causes weird things to happen and it ends up raising an exception with an unexpected class (i.e., not `RuntimeError`).

This bug was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/36a0e432f26cc3e52706c7be983a4c5f66844d29), and it is present in the [1.9.3 changelog](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_3_0/ChangeLog).

Ultimately, you do want to `raise exception`, not `raise exception.message`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I need to get better about reading c code. For clarity, it isn't that message returned a class per se, it just returned exactly whatever object was passed in, when it should have turned it into a string. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It should have returned a `String`, yes, however what it actually *did* return is a little harder to decipher. Calling `.class` on it yields `Class`, but there's likely a lot more oddness going on. It's harder to follow because it is in C (and C Ruby is huge).